# How to click on Metamask Start Botton with python using selenium and webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, metamask

Im trying to do a web scraper on python with selenium about an dapp where I need to log in with Metamask to scrape the information but I can´t clic on the start botton of Metamask. Maybe some of you can help. Maybe someone could help me understand why my code doesn't work.

I have tried to search the tag whit this diferent code but I still cant click:

```
1-driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Empezar"]').click()
2-driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Get Started"]').click()

3-WebDriverWait(driver, 5)\
    .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                      'button.button btn--rounded btn-primary first-time-flow__button'.replace(' ', '.'))))\
    .click()
```

This is my code. It opens metamask landpage but then it doesnt clic on the "Start" tag with classs = "button btn--rounded btn-primary first-time-flow__button".

```
#Librerias

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

#

Añadir Chrome options

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

#Ruta de metamask.crx para inicializar la aplicación

chrome_options.add_extension(r"C:\\Users\\34625\\OneDrive\\Luisyluis\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Proectos Personales\\programacion 2022\\Programacion Meta Soccer\\Metasoccerr\\metamask.crx")

#Opciones de Navegación

driver_path ='A:\WebDriver\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path,options=chrome_options)

    enter code here

#METAMASK - Click Empezar -- !!! THIS DOESN´T WORK 

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(

'//button[text()="Empezar"]').click()
```

Comment: Can you share the text based HTML source of the web elements, you wanted to click.

Comment: You are using `time.sleep(3)` and then `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Empezar"]').click()`, to me it does not sound like a time issue, may be your locator isn't unique in nature, Can you share the HTML code or link to the page ?

Comment: <button class="button btn--rounded btn-primary first-time-flow__button" role="button" tabindex="0">Empezar</button>

Comment: I have downloaded an extension from google in crx format (located in driver_path) and then I open the file  suing selenium. Before that, I need to clic on the "Empezar" botton

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fresher to use selenium, I found this problem, too. I had tried many times until I tried to use this code below before I got element. **Python version: 3.11.5**

```py
    driver.get("chrome-extension://alkhkbbpfhhihonfljaopkepefjicohg/home.html");
```

(you need to change  `alkhkbbpfhhihonfljaopkepefjicohg` to your own extension id). after that I can get the input element when I run this code below:

```py
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input').click()
```

which is represent the checkbox button.
Hope this answer can be helpful.

Comment: By the way, before I get element, I will switch to the window which is the last opened ```driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[len(driver.window_handles) - 1])```